# the program should find the maximum number in the array first time reading it as unsigned and second time as signed

Tags: assembly, x86-16

**loop does not work at all so i replaced it with decreasing CX and JNZ and it worked but when the program reaches the first DIV line it collapses, tested in turbo debugger it says it's dividing by zero!!**

````
    .STACK 100h
    .DATA
    ;definig variables and strings
    arr DW 1234h,5678h,0ff11h,1111h,2222h,3333h,4444h,5555h,6666h,7777h,8888h
    result1 DB 'Max for unsigned array is:00000','$'
    result2 DB 'Max for signed array is: 0000','$'
    len DW 11
    max DW ?
    TEN DB 1h
    .CODE
    progstart:
    MOV AX,@DATA             ; DS can be written to only through a register
   MOV DS,AX                ; Set DS to point to data segment
   MOV CX,len
    XOR SI,SI
    MOV AX,arr[0]
    MOV max,AX
    MOV BX,10
    do1:
    MOV AX,max
    cmp AX,arr[SI]
    JB  swap1
    ADD SI,2
    DEC CX
    JNZ do1
    MOV CX,4
    MOV AX,max
    MOV SI,31
    num2chU:
    DIV TEN    **THIS IS WHERE IT GETS STUCK**
    ADD AH,'0'
    MOV result1[SI],AH
    MOV AH,0
    DEC SI
    LOOP num2chU
    MOV DX,OFFSET result1  ;  Set  DS:DX to point to scannum1
    JMP print```
    ///CODE IS CUT///
````

Comment: Your debugger's message apparently assumes you're using `div` with the upper half of the dividend = 0, like compilers do.  But you're dividing a word by a byte, and faulting when the quotient overflows AL.  (Same `#DE` exception as divide by 0).  Divide by a `dw 10` instead after zeroing DX.

Comment: @PeterCordes thank you very much that was really helpful.